# ODBC Excel driver - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

When I run the following SQL statement in a VBA code (using an ADODB connection object):

```
UPDATE [MYTABLE$] SET LOCID = 'B036', REGISTER_NUMBER = '',
    PNAME = 'John Doe', GENDER = 1, IDNUMBER = '', BIRTHDAY = #8/8/1975#
WHERE MOGID = 'BER423'
```

I get the error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Excel driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

However, the following statement runs without error and returns the selected record:

```
SELECT MOGID,LOCID FROM [MYTABLE$] WHERE MOGID = 'BER423'
```

I have set the cell format of the MOGID column to 'text' but it doesn't help.

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Update one column at the time, and see which one that fails.

Comment: Hi thanks! I did that and the problem was with the field REGISTER_NUMBER that was assumed to be numeric but indeed it has to be alphanumeric.